# IOS Tab Bar in separate xib file

Tags: ios, interface, builder

I am new to programming in ios and I am trying to do something that I would think would be pretty simple but is turning out to be quite a stuggle. What I have done is created a window based app. Then I added a UIViewController subclass and checked "with xib for user interface". Then in my main application delegate I added an IBOutlet to the UIViewController subclass created and made it show when the application runs. Then in my mainwindow.xib file I linked the application delegate to the IBOutlet that I created. Now when I put a label on that view and run it, it works fine and shows my label. However, I am really unsure of how to make it display the tab bar control. I added the tab bar control but am unsure what to do after that. I have tried many things but nothing worked. If someone has any information on how to do this or something I am probably missing let me know.

Note: I have gotten the tab bar control to work in a window based app by adding the tab bar control and then in the application delegate adding the iboutlet and linking them in interface builder. However, i am unsure how to do it when using a different class to do so.

Any help is appreciated.